# Ruby Asynchronous Net::HTTP?

Tags: ruby, asynchronous, block, net-http

Does `Net::HTTP` support an asynchronous syntax?

I'm looking for something like the code below.

The block would get called on the main thread after `Net::HTTP` has either received the response from the server (in which case,`error` would be `nil`) or encountered an error connecting to the server (in which case `response` would be `nil`).

```
Net::HTTP.get('http://stackoverflow.com') do |response, error|
  if error
    puts "Connection error: #{error.message}"
  elsif response.status_code != HTTPOK
    puts "Unexpected status code: #{response.status_code}"
    puts response.body
  else
    puts "Success!"
    puts response.body
  end
end
```

The following questions provide answers but I'm looking for a block-based solution.

- [asynchronous http request in ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6643964/asynchronous-http-request-in-ruby)
- [Asynchronous HTTP requests with ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9344282/asynchronous-http-requests-with-ruby)

Answer (score 6):

Have a look at the `eventmachine` and `em-http-request` gems. The equivalent to your above code would be

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'eventmachine'
require 'em-http'

HTTP_OK = 200

EM.run do
  http = EM::HttpRequest.new('http://example.com').get

  http.errback do
    puts "Connection error: #{http.error}"
    EM.stop
  end

  http.callback do
    if http.response_header.status == HTTP_OK
      puts "Success!"
      puts http.response
    else
      puts "Unexpected status code: #{http.response_header.status}"
    end
    EM.stop
  end
end
```

There is a very good example using fibers on the [`em-http-request` Github page](https://github.com/igrigorik/em-http-request/blob/master/examples/fibered-http.rb).

**Edit:** I also recommend reading http://www.igvita.com/2009/05/13/fibers-cooperative-scheduling-in-ruby/

Comment: This is a good example, but testing a double negative seems like a bad idea. Testing for `== HTTP_OK` and then `else` would be easier to follow. Right now the success condition is "if not not okay".

Comment: @tadman thanks! you are right, fixed this. I guess i tried to reflect the op's code structure as much as possible.